# Does Magnific Popup support custom events/buttons

Tags: magnific-popup

I know Magnific Popup supports certain events such as Close, Next, etc. out of the box.  But does Magnific support custom buttons and events if I wanted to add my own event hooks, such as Download, email, buy, or whatever button I wanted to created.  I'm really just looking to be able to create my custom menu within the image 'div' area or directly beneath it. An example somewhere would be great.  I just haven't been able to find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before starting I would recommend reading the [Magnific Popup Documentation](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html) 
and familiarizing yourself with the available [examples](http://codepen.io/collection/nLcqo/), more specifically the Pin it button example.

Naturally, you will have to code out the functionality of your menu items as you need them.
For the how to's on the specifics of your buttons you will have to do more specific searching as it does not appear that there is a built in

```
magic(click, poof)
{
    //amazing things happen
}
```

function.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for setting us in the proper direction. The link to the Pin It example that has a custom button created is: http://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/hutrb

Comment: Thanks for the vote up!
Did you every get the functionality worked out?

Comment: that link is a 404, but I checked out some of your site and I really like the parallax scroll you've got going on there, really simple yet elegant - really nice work.

Comment: Updated with working link and thank you for your feedback: Yep. You can check the magnific popup implementation here: http://har-properties.com/allee-des-arts/availability - Click on the "B7b plan" link for example or on any link inside the plans. The functionality implemented is the zoom in/out on image click; and your answer set me in the right direction for the implementation. Thanks again :)